# IrDa connection from I:MX53 to Linux via IRmate 210

Tags: embedded, arm, infrared

I am trying to connect an I:MX53 board with my PC via IrDa.

So far i have gotten a connection established at 9600 bps, but as soon as I try to up the bitrate, I loose the data on my pc, even though I have set my serial read the same as the board send bitrate.

I can communicate succesfuly between two I:MX43 boards at 115.2kbps so i know that they both send and recieve correctly..

Am i missing something choosing bitrates with IrDa? some standards mayhaps?

**The Irmate 210 is 115.2kbps compatible.**

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the IRMate 210 unit needs to know the baud rate itself to be able to pass on the signals.. and then it works fine...